# How to use the same python decorator for all types of methods/functions?

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.7

If I have something like this :

```
class SomeClass(object):

    @classmethod
    @some_decorator
    def foo(cls, **kwargs):
        pass

    @some_decorator
    def bar(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    @some_decorator
    def bar(**kwargs):
        pass

@some_decorator
def function_outside_class(**kwargs):
    pass
```

How should I make that @some_decorator so that it will work on every type of function listed above? Basically for now I need that decorator to run some code after the method (close SQLAlchemy session). I had problems making any decorator work with methods that are allready decorated with @staticmethod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep the decorators in the order given in your post, a straight-forward implementation of the decorator should just work fine:

```
def some_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # Your code here
        return res
    return decorated
```

Note that you cannot do e.g.

```
@some_decorator
@staticmethod
def bar(**kwargs):
    pass
```

since a `staticmethod` object itself is not callable.

Comment: Would you care to expand on `staticmethod` objects not being callable, in light of this paste? I'm sure you're correct, but I think that statement is open to misinterpretation. http://pastebin.com/TUr3g3i0

Comment: @Marcin you need to call Foo.foo as method like Foo.foo(), if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @Sven Marnach I am shure I have tried it that way allready, but I`ll check it again tomorrow when I get back to the PC with that code, maybe I made some stupid typo..

Comment: @SašaŠijak: I'm not sure what you mean - in both cases, the call works just fine. The issue is with `staticmethod` objects.

Comment: @Marcin: A `staticmethod` object is a descriptor.  When retrieving it using `Foo.foo`, you'll get a callable object.  When you access it as `vars(Foo)["foo"]`, you will get the `staticmethod` object itself.  The latter is *not* callable, and this is what the outer decorator would see in the last code snippet.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yeah, it works, thanks. I really don`t know which error did I make, because I have tried this first and then lost an hour trying some other methods, overkilling it.